# How to declare a function throughout an angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have the following setup in an Angular5 using Angular-cli 1.5

in **typings.d.ts**

```
declare interface String {
   toSentenceCase(): string;
}
declare function _debug(o, message?, type?): void;
```

in **app/core/common.ts**

```
String.prototype.toSentenceCase = function () {
    return this.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.substring(1);
};
function _debug(o, message?, type?) {
    console.log(o);
}
```

in **main.ts**

```
import './app/core/common';
```

Now in my component

```
console.log('something'.toSentenceCase()); // works
_debug(data); // ERROR ReferenceError: _debug is not defined
```

Why did the prototype declaration go through, while the function was ignored?

Comment: you are importing from the `common` file but not `export`ing. example `export const my_constant = 'value'` and them in a component `import {my_contant} from '../path_to_common'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_debug` is defined in module scope and is not global. It could be defined as `window` property, but this won't work with Angular server side rendering.

Relying on globals is discouraged in modern JavaScript/TypeScript development, Angular in particular. A function should be exported from module and imported where it's used.

Comment: but the problem is that i use it EVERYWHERE, so it kind of noise to import it just about in all files... and calling _debug is so convenient, versus objectname._debug (or is there a way?)

Comment: You also use `Component` and `Injectable` in almost all files, but it wouldn't a good idea to expose them as globals. In order to refer it as _debug globally it should be defined as `window._debug = ...`. But it will have problems on server side, as it was mentioned. The best practice is to not do that in situations like this one but to import it every time it's used. IDEs can handle auto-imports automatically for you, that's why importing is not a problem.

Comment: Though that is an accepted answer, but I ended up adding a javascript function for it :( don't yet know how it would be handled in Agnular universal

Comment: The only consistent way to set up cross-platform global is `const global = eval('this'); global._debug = ...`. eval can fail with CSP but otherwise works in both Node and browser.

Comment: That made me think, jquery global is already installed, so why not use it? And that's what I did, $.myfunction whenever I need access to a global function, it does make development and maintenance much smoother

Comment: $ is not a namespace. Using $ for arbitrary tasks is infamous antipattern. There is a counterargument, which is *why use it*. And it shouldn't, because there are not enough reasons, unless you're developing jQuery plugin. It's even worse for Angular project than debug global.

Comment: I know, but up till this moment in time, I still rely heavily on jQuery, at least the slim version of it, so its a safe exit for me... today... not sure about tomorrow :)